# Whether Poisson noise will be dominant source of noise in low light conditions?

Tags: noise, image-processing

I have one [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/45c7/d1ee04b71077bb959c854343cf4d8836a3ed.pdf) saying that that the Poisson noise will be dominant source of noise in low light conditions and the [other](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hasinoff/pubs/hasinoff-photon-2012-preprint.pdf) one says the opposite way(Poisson noise will be dominant except in low light conditions). Which is true?
I believe Poisson noise is due to the random arrival of photons. So it should be more at short exposure time irrespective of light conditions.

Comment: Noise in **what system**? Photographic Film? Which kind of film? How do you choose your exposure time (which is very linked to the problem at hand)? And also, I find a **very** obvious difference in quality between the two papers. So maybe you can find a third paper.

Comment: CMOS sensor.. The exposure time will range from 15 - 40 ms..

Comment: So, please, hone your literature research skills a little more. Read the Hasinoff paper again. It does **not** claim that for high photon counts the distribution is Poisson. In fact, it claims the opposite

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on misreading the papers cited. "and for larger counts, the central limit theorem ensures that the Poisson distribution approaches a Gaussian." means that the Poisson distribution becomes a Gaussian distribution, not the opposite.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: "Its(Photon noise) expected magnitude is signal dependent and constitutes the dominant source of image noise except in low-light conditions".

Comment: @MarcusMüller What to infer from this line?

Comment: That the bad-quality Hasinoff paper contradicts itself and should not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hasinoff paper says:

> For small photon counts, photon noise is generally dominated by other
>   signal-independent sources of noise.

From my own experience with cameras I know that that is true. Even if the lens cap is on, the pixels will have dark current noise that is both spatially patterned and to a lesser extent varies by time. See for example this [Nikon D300 dark frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark-frame_subtraction#/media/File:Dark_Frame.jpg):

[image]

The Alter *et al.* paper only considers the low-light case. They do not take into account any time-varying component of the dark current noise. They do mention an "offset voltage", and take it into account in their noise model. Maybe their sensors are just very good with an almost perfectly constant offset voltage for each sensor element.

The dark current noise is **not** photon noise, because by definition there are no photons, but it is still Poisson-distributed (see Justin Charles Dunlap, [Characterization and Modeling of Nonlinear Dark Current in Digital Imagers](http://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3073&context=open_access_etds), 2014), independent of the signal. Because there are these two types of noise sources with Poisson statistics, I don't think it is wise to call photon noise *the* Poisson noise like Hasinoff does.

Comment: Thanks Olli.. One more doubt. Suppose if the lens cap is open and the scene is poorly lit. But we are able to see the details by applying some gain over the image. What is the property of noise in this case?

Comment: It's the Poisson dark current noise plus Poisson photon noise... in total still roughly Poisson I guess altough the quanta might differ and I don't know how the signal itself comes to the picture. And on top of that quantization noise.